# Android VS Emulator not recognizing work Network

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium

I am trying to set up a selenium/appium framework to test an application on a range of different android devices. As the application is still in the build phase, we are require to be connected to my work network to be able to log into the application itself.

The issue I am having is that if i am using the android VS emulators, I am not able to log into the application.

Whereas if i use BlueStacks to install and run the application, I am able to access the application.

My question is, is here any settings I need to change to make the Android VS emulators to recognize that I am on the work network. Or could you point me in a direction I can investigate?

I am using Appium and the server address is `127.0.0.1:4723.`

Comment: obviously it is because 127.0.0.1 ... for emulator it is emulator itself not emulator 's host

Comment: Even if I run the android emulator directly from Android Studio without appium server running I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using VS Emulator? On [this page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) they state:

> Note: After we released the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, Google updated their Android emulator to use hardware acceleration.
>
> We recommend you use Google’s emulator when you can, as it offers access to the latest Android OS images and Google Play services. If you have enabled Hyper-V, try out our Hyper-V Android emulator compatibility preview to run Google’s emulator on Hyper-V directly.

You should use the official Android Studio emulator which lets you control network connectivity:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#wi-fi
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking